# jquery's val() doesn't set 'selected' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery to create select options field in a table. but for unknown reason I'm not able to set the selected option.

In the example below, there are four select options and only the last one has the correct option selected. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with my code?

**EDIT:**
I changed to code snippet. Now we have 3 examples:
**1)** Original example that I posted. val() works only on second select option
**2)** Same as 1, but appending to DOM is done by ID not class. Here only the second select option is set correctly
**3)** select option is defined in HTML. val() is used to select option 2. Here it works ok.

**Questions:**
**1)** why in example 1, only the second select option is set correctly
**2)** why in exmpale 2, the first select option is not renderred at all.

I know that workaround is to select correct option by setting attribute "selected" on "option" element, but the behaviour of method val() in my opinion is not consistent and I wanted to understand why. maybe i'm using it not as designed, but so far cannot say so.

```js
//example 1
$('<select />')
.append($('<option/>', { value: "1" }).text("first option"))
.append($('<option/>', { value: "2" }).text("second option"))
.append($('<option/>', { value: "3" }).text("third option"))
.val("2")
.appendTo($('.td1'));

//example 2
$('<select />')
.append($('<option/>', { value: "1" }).text("first option"))
.append($('<option/>', { value: "2" }).text("second option"))
.append($('<option/>', { value: "3" }).text("third option"))
.val("2")
.appendTo($('#td21'))
.appendTo($('#td22'));
//example 3
$('.td3 select').val("2");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th title="val() works only on last rendered element">Example 1</th>
      <th title="val() works, but only one element is rendered at all">Example 2</th>
      <th title="val() works OK!">Example 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td1"></td>
      <td class="td2" id="td21"></td>
      <td class="td3">
        <select class="select3">
          <option value="1">first option</option>
          <option value="2">second option</option>
          <option value="3">third option</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td1"></td>
      <td class="td2" id="td22"></td>
      <td class="td3">
        <select class="select3">
          <option value="1">first option</option>
          <option value="2">second option</option>
          <option value="3">third option</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The issue is because you're setting the value, not the `selected` attribute on the `option` within the select. Therefore when the element is cloned between the `.col2` elements there is no `selected` option. For that you'd need to set `val()` individually or put a `selected` attribute directly on the `option` when you create the select.

Comment: According to JQuery documentation val() can be used to set selected attribute (http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2). there is an example  of setting up selection on a single and multiple select option.

Comment: That's right - but note that it sets the *property*, not the *attribute*. Hence the problem you have, and why the solution below works.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm not sure If I understand your point. val() works fine on select options, but not in all cases. Please have a look at my example (edited snippet code).when I debugged val() method I found out that for select node it actually operates on an options collection and sets the property "selected" (there is an extension method valHooks for select).

Answer (score 2):

You can preselect an option by giving it the attribute `selected` like this :

```
.append($('<option/>', {
    value: "2",
    selected: true
})
```

```js
$('<select />')
  .append($('<option/>', {
    value: "1"
  }).text("first option"))
  .append($('<option/>', {
    value: "2",
    selected: true
  }).text("second option"))
  .append($('<option/>', {
    value: "3"
  }).text("third option"))
  .appendTo($('.col2'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<TABLE>
  <TBODY>
    <TR DATA-INDEX='1'>
      <TD>11</TD>
      <TD class='col2'>12</TD>
      <TD>13</TD>
      <TD class='col4'>14</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR DATA-INDEX='2'>
      <TD>21</TD>
      <TD class='col2'>22</TD>
      <TD>23</TD>
      <TD class='col4'>24</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR DATA-INDEX='3'>
      <TD>31</TD>
      <TD class='col2'>32</TD>
      <TD>33</TD>
      <TD class='col4'>34</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR DATA-INDEX='4'>
      <TD>41</TD>
      <TD class='col2'>42</TD>
      <TD>43</TD>
      <TD class='col4'>44</TD>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Or you can select your option after the fact like this :

```
.find('option[value="2"]').prop('selected',true‌​)
```

```js
$('<select />')
      .append($('<option/>', {
        value: "1"
      }).text("first option"))
      .append($('<option/>', {
        value: "2"
      }).text("second option"))
      .append($('<option/>', {
        value: "3"
      }).text("third option"))
      .appendTo($('.col2'))
      .find('option[value="2"]').prop('selected',true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<TABLE>
  <TBODY>
    <TR DATA-INDEX='1'>
      <TD>11</TD>
      <TD class='col2'>12</TD>
      <TD>13</TD>
      <TD class='col4'>14</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR DATA-INDEX='2'>
      <TD>21</TD>
      <TD class='col2'>22</TD>
      <TD>23</TD>
      <TD class='col4'>24</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR DATA-INDEX='3'>
      <TD>31</TD>
      <TD class='col2'>32</TD>
      <TD>33</TD>
      <TD class='col4'>34</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR DATA-INDEX='4'>
      <TD>41</TD>
      <TD class='col2'>42</TD>
      <TD>43</TD>
      <TD class='col4'>44</TD>
    </TR>
  </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. In my application I have many select option fields created dynamically in a table. I'm looking for a solution where i don't have to loop over a list of options and check on which I have to set the attribute "selected". with val() method the loop is done implicitly, so the code looks cleaner.

Comment: @user1308240 Then set your option attribute after the fact : `....find('option[value="'+yourVal+'"]').prop('selected',true)`